# Табы с плагином SelectBoxIt

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет!! Я использую плагин SelectBoxIt для стилизации элемента select. Но нужно на основе этого select сделать табы(вкладки), контент которых менялся бы в зависимости от выбранного пункта. Так, как SelectBoxIt прячет элемент select, я не понимаю как реализовать это. Может, кто сталкивался?

Comment: пример кода можно???

Comment: @Demon__ANT к сожалению, нет)) обычные табы на select я могу реализовать. Но вот с использованием плагина, нет. Я не пойму к чему привязываться